# How best to use react-router with dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building an app that utilises the Dropbox api.

I have an *index* component that lists all folders in a Dropbox directory.

I then have a *projects* component that receives props from it's parent when one of the directory links are clicked. This populates the component with images inside that folder directory.

Using react-router, I want to modify the url to the directory name, and for that url to display that folder only.

**I am unsure of the best way to proceed** - do I need to create separate components for all the subfolders in the directory, or is there a way of still having one component that is updated dynamically?

I've been working through the *react-router* section of *reacttraining* but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        imageSource: [],
        imageTitles: [],
        setProjectTitle: null,
     }
    this.indexTitleClick = this.indexTitleClick.bind(this)
  }

  indexTitleClick(title) {
    this.setState({
       setProjectTitle: title,
    });
   }

  componentDidMount(){
    var sources = [];
    var titles =[];

    dbx.filesListFolder({path: ''})
      .then(function(response) {

        ...
        ...
        //pulling data from Dropbox api
        ...
        ...

      .then(function(){
        this.setState({
          imageSource: sources,
          imageTitles: titles,

        });
      });

  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Index imageSource={this.state.imageSource} imageTitles=
        {this.state.imageTitles} indexTitleClick = 
        {this.indexTitleClick}/>
        <Project title={this.state.setProjectTitle}/>
      </div>
    );
}
}



class Index extends React.Component{

  render(){
     if(!this.props.imageSource.length)
     return null;

     let titles = this.props.imageTitles.map((el, i) => <p>{el}</p>)
     let links = this.props.imageTitles
     let images = this.props.imageSource.map((el, i) =>

       <div className="imageContainer">
         <img key={i} className='indexImages' src={el} onClick = 
           {this.props.indexTitleClick.bind(this,titles[i])}/>
           <Link to={"/projects/"+links[i]} className="imageTitle" onClick = {this.props.indexTitleClick.bind(this,titles[i])}>{titles[i]}
         </Link>
       </div>
      );



        return (
            <div className="indexWrapper">
                {images}
            </div>

        );
  }
}

class Project extends React.Component{


  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      imageSource: [],
    }
  }

 componentDidMount(){
   var sources = [];
     var link = "/"+this.props.title.props.children;

     dbx.filesListFolder({path: link})
       .then(function(response) {

        ...
        ...
        //pulling data from Dropbox api
        ...
        ...

       .then(function(){
          this.setState({
            imageSource: sources,
          });
       });
     });
   }

    render() {

      if(!this.state.imageSource.length)
        return null;
        let images = this.state.imageSource.map((el, i) =>
          <img key={i} className='projectImages' src={el}/>
       )

     return (
       <div className="projectWrapper">
         <div className="imageWrapper">
           {images}
         </div>

         <div className="projectHeader">
           <div className="projectTitle">{this.props.title}</div>
             <Link to ="/index" className="backBtn" onClick = 
            {this.props.projectBackClick}><p>Back</p></Link>
         </div>
      </div>
     );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need to create separate components for all the subfolders in the directory. Probably your `routes` config looks something like this:

```
<Route path="/index" component={Index} />
<Route path="/projects/:projectPath" component={Parent} />
...
```

In the `Parent` component you can now read `projectPath` from the props and pass it to the `Project`.

```
const projectPath = props.params.projectPath;
...
<Project path={projectPath} />
```

Comment: Can you please clarify where I should be placing `const projectPath = props.params.projectPath; ` ?

Comment: You can place it in the render method of the `Parent` component: `const projectPath = this.props.params.projectPath;` or you can pass the value directly to the Project component: `<Project path={this.props.params.projectPath} />`. Then in the `Project` component you can get `path` from the props.